# How to render list according to localStorage input.value?

Tags: javascript, events

I wrote a function that trigger on input and get data from API. I need to store last input.value in localStorage and then set input.value to one in localStorage on reload. Everything is fine except when I reload the page I have value that I need but I have to click space then backspace f.e. to render things. I would like to ask where should I pass the getter from localStorage so it will trigger the function on reload, but won't break the listener for input. There is full code underneath :

```
let country;
let cities = [];
const citiesDiv = document.getElementById("cities");
const countryPicker = document.getElementById("country-picker");

const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.openaq.org/v1/cities?country=${country}&limit=10&parameter=no2&order_by=parameter`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  cities = data.results;
  console.log(cities);
  citiesDiv.innerHTML = "";
  renderCities(cities);
};

countryPicker.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("inputValue"));

countryPicker.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "poland".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "PL";
  } else if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "spain".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "ES";
  } else if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "germany".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "DE";
  } else if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "france".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "FR";
  }
  localStorage.setItem("inputValue", JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
  getData();
});

function renderCities(cities) {
  cities.forEach(function(city) {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.classList.add("accordion");
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("panel");
    const citiesDiv = document.getElementById("cities");
    button.textContent = city.city;
    citiesDiv.appendChild(button);
    citiesDiv.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(p);
    p.textContent = "Lorem ipsum";
  });
  const acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  let i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your code in order to make the function that fetches and renders data to be reusable for two cases:

1. when user changes the `input`.
2. when the page is loaded.

Replace the following part

```
countryPicker.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("inputValue"));

countryPicker.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "poland".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "PL";
  } else if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "spain".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "ES";
  } else if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "germany".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "DE";
  } else if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === "france".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "FR";
  }
  localStorage.setItem("inputValue", JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
  getData();
});
```

with

```
countryPicker.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("inputValue"));
fetchAndRender(countryPicker.value);

countryPicker.addEventListener("input", e => fetchAndRender(e.target.value));

function fetchAndRender(value) {
  if (value.toLowerCase() === "poland".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "PL";
  } else if (value.toLowerCase() === "spain".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "ES";
  } else if (value.toLowerCase() === "germany".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "DE";
  } else if (value.toLowerCase() === "france".toLowerCase()) {
    country = "FR";
  }
  localStorage.setItem("inputValue", JSON.stringify(value));
  getData();
}
```